# How to automatically flow the div block to the next row with css?

Tags: css, 960.gs

i am using a 960gs to create a site, I have product blocks like the one in the eCommerce site, i wanted to show them continually like 4x5 blocks, I mean 4 blocks in a column and 5 blocks in row totaling 20 blocks,

My problem is first row require to put "alpha" and "omega" to the divs, How can I put them programatically, because I am using wordpress, and the products are in it.

Can anyone get what I am saying?

Comment: TBH, your question makes very little sense. Try including code samples and links to prototypes as a minimum. When requesting help with layouts, SO users usually find the required layout as annotated images very handy.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the code that you are using so this is very abstract.

Wordpress uses php templates for each product I'm guessing... That means there has to be a php loop somewhere that enumerates all the products that will appear in your row. You can do an if statement there. Something like:  if first product add class alpha to template,  if last product add class omega to template else print regular template

Additionally you can add it on the client side after page load using javascript and li:first-child and li:last-child css selectors but you might see a bit of a flicker on page load.